# Is there a high performance Fortran compiler for Linux?

Tags: linux, fortran

Right now I use Sun-Studio, but Oracle is asking ridiculously high license fees for it.

Is there a high performance Fortran compiler for Linux that is comparable with Sun-Studio's performance?

GNU's Fortran compiler is a lot slower.

Comment: I thought Solaris Studio was free? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html

Comment: Yes.   I just downloaded SunStudio f http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html.   You need a (free) Oracle account.

Comment: There is also Pathscale Ekopath. Link [here](http://www.pathscale.com/ekopath.html), or directly [here](http://c591116.r16.cf2.rackcdn.com/ekopath/nightly/Linux/ekopath-2013-08-08-installer.run) for latest build (for some reason, the link on Pathscale's site is a bit old). [They said](http://www.pathscale.com/ekopath4-open-source-announcement) once they were going open source, but I'm not sure they finally did.

Comment: And [open64](http://www.open64.net/), derived from [SGI MIPSPro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open64), yet running on Intel architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel Fortran compiler is available as "try before buy", you can find it [here](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/AutoGen.aspx?ProductID=1521&AccountID=&EmailID=&ProgramID=&RequestDt=&rm=EVAL&lang=).

Comment: Intel Fortran is rather fast, according to [Polyhedron](http://polyhedron.com/pb05-lin64-f90bench_SBhtml). Also, it's not just "try before use", but ***free for non-commercial development*** : see [here](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/RegCenter/NComForm.aspx?ProductID=1501). Btw, your link does not seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Solaris Studio is (still) a free download. What's might be expensive is a full support contract. 
It's still the best compiler for HPC applications on Solaris (SPARC and x86) and Linux (x86).

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/index.html

There are lots of technical articles, community forums, and full documentation on the website.

Comment: The way I understand it, you can download the latest beta, but if you want the latest stable version, you have to pay.

Comment: Newer link [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html)